# What is the needs of {inheritdoc}?

Tags: php, drupal

I am dealing with Drupal and classes a lot and sometime i read something like:

```
/**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */

  // return the form definition
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $config = $this->config('hello_world.custom_salutation');

    $form['salutation'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Salutation'),
      '#description' => $this->t('Si prega di inserire il saluto che si desidera usare'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('salutation'),
    );
```

what is the meaning of inheritdoc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a *docblock* syntax that is part of Drupal's [API documentation and comment standards](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/api-documentation-and-comment-standards) :

You may use `{@inheritdoc}` in a class

> if you are overriding or implementing a method from a base
> class or interface, and the documentation should be exactly the same
> as the base class/interface method

It also states that this *must be the only line in the docblock.*

Comment: ... "must be the only line". Which is annoying since you might want to document some implementation detail.

Comment: Yes it'd be useful to at least be able to override it (never tried though, maybe they meant "must be the only *docblock {}* line" which would make more sense..)

Answer (score 0):

## Stop using {@inheritdoc} from 2023

Using {@inheritdoc} in docblocks is today (in the year 2023 onwards) probably redundant, as tooling has evolved and is able to determine inheritance independently.

Drupal 8 onward biggest dependency is Symfony. Symfony 6.2 dropped {@inheritdoc} (read: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/47390) on the basis that:

> It looks like this PHP Doc is useless. IDEs are able to inherit the
> doc (at least VS Code and PHP Storm). And tools like PHP Stan are able
> to too https://phpstan.org/r/74a2c008-ff2b-42c0-8edf-8da87c1a7b5f

Read this for drupal developers: https://www.drupal.org/project/coding_standards/issues/3335320